# por que no se muestra mi animación QLabel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

quiero poner como fondo de una label una animacion.gif para lo que oucpo la propiedad `QMovie` dentro de mi función `def anmima()`, que se activa al hacer click en el boton `self.l_entrar`

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.Qt import QMovie
from FirebaseLogin import *
from contraInicio import ContraInicioC
from Principal import PrincipalC
from MostrarDatosTabla import mostararDatos
from CrearFirebase import crear_tabla
from sucursalInicio import sucursal
import sqlite3
import threading

class LoginC(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("Interfaz/Login.ui",self)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.l_permiso.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoMousePropagation)
        self.l_sucursal.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoMousePropagation)

        self.l_close.clicked.connect(self.close)



        self.contraseña = ContraInicioC()
        self.principal = PrincipalC()
        self.l_entrar.clicked.connect(self.setDataPrincipal)
        self.l_permiso.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda:self.cambioPermiso(self.l_permiso.currentText()))
        self.l_permiso.setCurrentText("Caja")
        self.suc = sucursal
        self.l_sucursal.setCurrentText(self.suc)
        #self.principal.pc_fecha.setDate(QtCore.QDate.currentDate())



    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def cambioPermiso(self,permiso):
        if permiso == "Administrador":

            self.l_sucursal.setEnabled(True)
        else:

            self.l_sucursal.setEnabled(False)

    def setDataPrincipal(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.anima)
        t.start()

        self.estado = 0
        fechaActual = QtCore.QDate.currentDate().toPyDate()

        ref = db.reference("/"+str(fechaActual))
        ret = ref.get()

        if ret == None:
            print("creada")
            crear_tabla(str(fechaActual))
            self.estado = 0
            if self.l_permiso.currentIndex()==1:
                self.principal.pc_sucursal.setEnabled(False)
                self.principal.pc_fecha.setDate(QtCore.QDate.currentDate())
                self.principal.pc_sucursal.setCurrentText(self.l_sucursal.currentText())
                self.principal.show()

            else:
                print("value")
                #self.contraseña.datos(self.l_permiso.currentText(), "Matutino", self.l_sucursal.currentText(),self.estado,self.principal.p_referencia)
                self.contraseña.permiso = self.l_permiso.currentText()
                self.contraseña.turno = "Matutino"
                self.contraseña.sucursal = self.l_sucursal.currentText()
                self.contraseña.estado = self.estado
                self.contraseña.referencia = self.principal.p_referencia
                self.contraseña.show()
        else:
            self.estado =1
            print("actualizada")
            #mostararDatos(str(fechaActual),self.l_sucursal.currentText(),"Matutino",self.principal.saldo,self.principal.tablaM,self.principal.inventario,self.principal.p_referencia)

            if self.l_permiso.currentIndex()==1:
                self.principal.pc_sucursal.setEnabled(False)
                self.principal.pc_fecha.setDate(QtCore.QDate.currentDate())
                self.principal.pc_sucursal.setCurrentText(self.l_sucursal.currentText())
                self.principal.show()

            else:

                #self.contraseña.datos(self.l_permiso.currentText(), "Matutino", self.l_sucursal.currentText(),self.estado,self.principal.p_referencia)
                self.contraseña.permiso = self.l_permiso.currentText()
                self.contraseña.turno = "Matutino"
                self.contraseña.sucursal = self.l_sucursal.currentText()
                self.contraseña.estado = self.estado
                self.contraseña.referencia = self.principal.p_referencia
                self.contraseña.show()


        self.principal.o_sucursal.setText(self.l_sucursal.currentText())
        self.principal.o_turno.setText("Matutino")
        self.principal.o_permiso.setText(self.l_permiso.currentText())
        #self.principal.pc_sucursal.setCurrentText(self.l_sucursal.currentText())
        #self.principal.pc_fecha.setDate(QtCore.QDate.currentDate())
        self.close()

    def mousePressEvent(self,event):

        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.dragPosition = event.globalPos() - self.frameGeometry().topLeft()
            event.accept()


    def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.move(event.globalPos() - self.dragPosition)
            event.accept()
    def anima(self):
        self.movie = QMovie("uno.gif")
        self.label.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()

app = QApplication([])
l = LoginC()
l.show()
app.exec_()
```

ARCHIVO.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <ui version="4.0">
         <class>MainWindow</class>
         <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
          <property name="geometry">
           <rect>
            <x>0</x>
            <y>0</y>
            <width>650</width>
            <height>370</height>
           </rect>
          </property>
          <property name="windowTitle">
           <string>MainWindow</string>
          </property>
          <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
            <property name="geometry">
             <rect>
              <x>0</x>
              <y>0</y>
              <width>650</width>
              <height>370</height>
             </rect>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string/>
            </property>
           </widget>
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="l_close">
            <property name="geometry">
             <rect>
              <x>620</x>
              <y>0</y>
              <width>31</width>
              <height>23</height>
             </rect>
            </property>
            <property name="font">
             <font>
              <pointsize>9</pointsize>
              <weight>75</weight>
              <bold>true</bold>
             </font>
            </property>
            <property name="styleSheet">
             <string notr="true">QPushButton#l_close{
        background:none;
        border:0px;
        color:grey;
        }
        QPushButton#l_close:hover{
        color:red;
        }</string>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>X</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
           <widget class="QLabel" name="lsucursal">
            <property name="geometry">
             <rect>
              <x>380</x>
              <y>330</y>
              <width>51</width>
              <height>22</height>
             </rect>
            </property>
            <property name="styleSheet">
             <string notr="true">color:grey;
        background:none;</string>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Sucursal:</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
           <widget class="QLabel" name="la">
            <property name="geometry">
             <rect>
              <x>220</x>
              <y>330</y>
              <width>51</width>
              <height>22</height>
             </rect>
            </property>
            <property name="styleSheet">
             <string notr="true">color:grey;
        background:none;</string>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Permisos</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
           <widget class="QComboBox" name="l_permiso">
            <property name="geometry">
             <rect>
              <x>268</x>
              <y>330</y>
              <width>91</width>
              <height>22</height>
             </rect>
            </property>
            <property name="styleSheet">
             <string notr="true">QComboBox#l_permiso{
        background:none;
        border:0px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid lightblue;
        color:#05839C;
        }


        QComboBox QAbstractItemView
        {
            border:0px;
            background:white;
            color: grey;

        }
        QComboBox#l_permiso::drop-down
        {
             subcontrol-origin: padding;
             subcontrol-position: top right;
             width: 15px;
             color: white;
             border-left-width: 0px;
             border-left-color: darkgray;
             border-left-style: solid; /* just a single line */
             border-top-right-radius: 3px; /* same radius as the QComboBox */
             border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
             padding-left: 10px;
         }</string>
            </property>
            <item>
             <property name="text">
              <string>Administrador</string>
             </property>
            </item>
            <item>
             <property name="text">
              <string>Caja</string>
             </property>
            </item>
           </widget>
           <widget class="QComboBox" name="l_sucursal">
            <property name="enabled">
             <bool>false</bool>
            </property>
            <property name="geometry">
             <rect>
              <x>440</x>
              <y>330</y>
              <width>69</width>
              <height>22</height>
             </rect>
            </property>
            <property name="styleSheet">
             <string notr="true">QComboBox#l_sucursal{
        background:none;
        border:0px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid lightblue;
        color:#05839C;
        }


        QComboBox QAbstractItemView
        {
            border:0px;
            background:white;
            color: grey;

        }
        QComboBox#l_sucursal::drop-down
        {
             subcontrol-origin: padding;
             subcontrol-position: top right;
             width: 15px;
             color: white;
             border-left-width: 0px;
             border-left-color: darkgray;
             border-left-style: solid; /* just a single line */
             border-top-right-radius: 3px; /* same radius as the QComboBox */
             border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
             padding-left: 10px;
         }</string>
            </property>
            <item>
             <property name="text">
              <string>Exxe 1</string>
             </property>
            </item>
            <item>
             <property name="text">
              <string>Exxe 3</string>
             </property>
            </item>
           </widget>
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="l_entrar">
            <property name="geometry">
             <rect>
              <x>550</x>
              <y>330</y>
              <width>75</width>
              <height>22</height>
             </rect>
            </property>
            <property name="styleSheet">
             <string notr="true">QPushButton#l_entrar{
        background:#41CD52;
        border:0px;
        color:white;
        }
        QPushButton#l_entrar:pressed{
        border-bottom:2px solid green;
        }
        </string>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Entrar</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </widget>
         </widget>
         <resources/>
         <connections/>
        </ui>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

AL OPRIMIR EL BOTON ENTRAR NO COLOCA LA ANIMACION EN EL QLABEL

**NOTA:**

Si al boton `self.l_entrar`, solo le asigno la funcion `self.anima`, la animación di funciona pero si por el contrario a `self.l_entrar` le asigno la funcion `setDataPrincipal`y dentro de ella llamo a la funcion `self.anima` no funciona la animacion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas utilizar la librería de threading, ni poner el QMovie en un Thread para que corra en paralelo. Qt maneja sus propios threads de sus objetos, y no permite que se inicien clases desde otros threads, lo cual es probable que te causara el fallo. Con Qt tienes a tu disposición [QThread (en inglés)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html).

Cambia:

```
    t = threading.Thread(target=self.anima)
    t.start()
```

Por:

```
    self.anima()
```

También te recomiendo cambiar `uic.loadUi("Interfaz/Login.ui",self)` por `self.ui = uic.loadUi("Interfaz/Login.ui",self)`, para tener un acceso a los elementos de la ui mas limpios, pero no es necesario.

El código mínimo y funcional queda así:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.Qt import QMovie

class LoginC(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("main.ui",self) //Cambia esto por tu ubicacion del .ui

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.ui.l_permiso.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoMousePropagation)
        self.ui.l_sucursal.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoMousePropagation)

        self.ui.l_entrar.clicked.connect(self.anima)
        self.ui.l_close.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def anima(self):
        self.movie = QMovie("uno.gif")
        self.label.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()

app = QApplication([])
l = LoginC()
l.show()
app.exec_()
```

[image: Domostración de funcionamiento de GIF]

También reduje tu código, ya que no lo podía probar, te recomiendo que pongas un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) la próxima vez.

Comment: No funciono, si ejecuto el codigo sin alguna otra funcion si corre pero al integrar la funcion setDataPincipal ya no hace nada

Comment: No puedo probar tu función de setDataPrincipal, ya que depende de otras librerías que no publicaste. Lo que puedo ver de tu ejemplo es que no está definido db.

Comment: db lo importo de FirebaseLogin, y no puedo poner todos los archivos yua que son varios,

Comment: El problema entonces yace en tus otros archivos, lo que demostré en el código es que QMovie funciona de la manera esperada, cargando un gif y animando como es esperado. Varias pueden ser las razones, la mas común es que un hilo saturado no permita que Qt refresque su interfaz. Prueba a meter en un hilo alguna ejecución larga que se haga en ella.